# 2-Dimension array of List in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I just want get a 2 dimension array of List in c#. In my thought, below should works but it didn't, the 1 dimension array of List works. I use Unity3D with Mono, however I think it's language related problem.

```
List<MyType>[,] twoDArrayofList;//don't work, it's type is List<MyType>
List<MyType>[] oneDArrayofList;//it's works, the type is List<MyType>
```

Anyone know what's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665299/are-2-dimensional-lists-possible-in-c

Comment: @Marshal I have checked that question, that's different problem, anyway thank you for the fast feedback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What error are you getting?

I don't know about Mono (or Unity3D), but I just tried the following in a .NET project and got the results I expected:

```
List<string>[,] strings = new List<string>[2, 2];
strings[0, 0] = new List<string> { "One" };
strings[0, 1] = new List<string> { "Two" };
strings[1, 0] = new List<string> { "Three" };
strings[1, 1] = new List<string> { "Four" };
```

Comment: I figure it out, it's the the IDE MonoDeveloper error, the IDE can't recognize this situation, and give me a wrong type, what a shame. Thanks for your answer let me start checking the IDE

Answer (score 0):

This is an older post, but it came up in my search for a similar answer. I found that creating a Dictionary instead of a List meets my needs. You can't iterate by index, but if you have a discrete list and you are iterating through the first string "Key", you can easily obtain the second string "Value".

Here is a stackoverflow post with examples:
[What is the best way to iterate over a Dictionary in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c)