# Succinct syntax for initializing list of lists

Tags: c#

Is there a concise syntax for intializing lists of lists in C#?

I tried

```
new List<List<int>>{
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5},
    {6,7,8,9}
};
```

But I get an error 'No overload for method 'Add' takes 3 arguments'

---

Edit: I know about the long syntax

```
 new List<List<int>>{
    new List<int>           {1,2,3},
    new List<int>           {4,5},
    new List<int>           {6,7,8,9}
};
```

I was just searching for something pithier.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665299/are-2-dimensional-lists-possible-in-c

Comment: Not an answer but you could do something like this if you were using arrays: `new List<int[]> { new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new[] { 4, 5, 6 } };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the introduction of [target-typed `new` expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new) in **[C# 9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9)/[.NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)**, you can now create a `List<List<T>>` more succinctly as follows:

```
new List<List<int>>{
    new () {1,2,3},
    new () {4,5},
    new () {6,7,8,9}
};
```

This works with [dictionary initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer) as well, e.g.

```
new List<Dictionary<string, int>>{
    new () {{"foo", 1}, {"bar", 2}}
};
```

or

```
new List<Dictionary<string, int>>{
    new () {["foo"] = 1, ["bar"] = 2}
};
```

Answer (score 6):

No, you need `new List<int>` for each:

```
var lists = new List<List<int>>() { 
    new List<int>{1,2,3},
    new List<int>{4,5},
    new List<int>{6,7,8,9}
};
```