# c# initialize a static list in a class

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to have is a 2D global list initialized with strings.
If I only wanted a simple list I could just initialize the list with strings separated by a comma like this

```cs
public static readonly List<string> _architecturesName = new List<string>() {"x86","x64" };
```

I have set up a static class `Globals`, in this class I'm adding a List based on another class `ArchitecturesClass` to be used as fields for the list similar to what was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665299/are-2-dimensional-lists-possible-in-c)

```cs
public class ArchecturesClass
{  
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// test1 : 
public static readonly List<ArchecturesClass> ArchitectureList =  new List<ArchecturesClass>() { "2", "9"}; 
    
// test2 : 
public static readonly List<ArchecturesClass> ArchitectureList = new List<ArchecturesClass>() 
    {
        architecturesId = "2",
        architecturesName = "3"
    };
```

The error on the strings is that the collection initialize has some invalid arguments and
In the end, I want all classes in the project to be able to read something like Globals.ArchtecutreList.ID and a matching `Globals.ArchtecutreList.Name;` and I would like to initialize this in the global class without being in a method.

Comment: You cannot initialize the list with values that belong to the object. You have to create a new object and use the shorthand assignments there.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The syntax

```
new List<ArchecturesClass>() {architecturesId = "2",
                              architecturesName = "3"};
```

should probably be

```
new List<ArchecturesClass>() { new ArchecturesClass>() { architecturesId = "2",
                              architecturesName = "3"}};
```

[Collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx) expect you to provide instances of the type contained in your list.

Your other attempt

```
public static readonly List<ArchecturesClass> ArchitectureList = 
       new List<ArchecturesClass>() { "2", "9"};
```

fails because "2" and "9" are strings, not instances of `ArchitecturesClass`.

Comment: Almost, i think this got it:         public static List<ArchecturesClass> archs = new List<ArchecturesClass> 
            {
                new ArchecturesClass() { architecturesId = "0", architecturesName= "x86"},
                new ArchecturesClass() { architecturesId = "9", architecturesName= "x64"} 
            };   Also found this ref which has a good example at bottom http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062(v=vs.100).aspx