# How can you save a column and row to one variable in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have a row a column saved by using the following two lines of code:

```
private List<Tile[]> columns = new List<Tile[]>();
private List<Tile[]> rows = new List<Tile[]>();
```

Is there a way to create a variable that can take the column and index so that I can get the location of where the user clicked? Something like this:

```
indexOfClick = [row, column];
```

EDIT: How I'm adding a column and row:

```
columns.Add(new Tile[]{AllTiles[0, 0], AllTiles[1, 0], AllTiles[2, 0], AllTiles[3, 0] });

rows.Add(new Tile[]{AllTiles[0, 0], AllTiles[0, 1], AllTiles[0, 2], AllTiles[0, 3] });
```

Comment: Can you post how you add a column/row?

Comment: Could you give us some example?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto added extra code showing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are 2 dimensional Lists possible in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665299/are-2-dimensional-lists-possible-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [tuples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/) for this :

```
var indexOfClick = (row, column);
```

Comment: I tried a tuple but it gives me an error because the version of C# that I'm using with Unity doesn't support tuples.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a custom **Struct** or **Class**:

```cs
public class Cell
{
    public int Row { get; }
    public int Column { get; }

    public Cell(int row, int column)
    {
        Row = row;
        Column = column;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you may use [Tuple Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple) or [ValueTuple Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unity's built in integer-vector struct:

```
    List<Vector2Int> Coords;
```

and thus

```
    Coords.Add( new Vector2Int( clickX, clickY ) );
```